# How to use current chrome with selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to use my local chrome with selenium, but every time I just get a new chrome without any cookies

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument(r'--user-data-dir=/Users/mac/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default') 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=option, executable_path="/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
driver.get("https://twitter.com/")
```

- my chrome user data dir

[image]

**I want to use default chrome with selenium, then how to setup chrome options?**

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to mention the Chrome profile directory like below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

option.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=/Users/mac/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/")
option.add_argument("--profile-directory=Default")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=option, executable_path="/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
driver.get("https://twitter.com/")
```

Before executing the code, close all the Chrome browser windows and chromedriver.exe then try.

Comment: It works. Thanks. I need to close all the chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

First, install this chrome package

```
pip install undetected-chromedriver
```

then, you can load profiles, plugins, and customize settings very easily.

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

if __name__ == '__main__':
    options = uc.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument(f'--user-data-dir=c:\\temp\\chrome-profile') # chrome profile location
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_argument('--no-first-run --no-service-autorun --password-store=basic')
    options.add_argument('--load-extension=C:\\temp\\plugin-folder')
    driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.get('https://www.google.com')
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: I had tried as your code use `undetected_chromedriver`  and set `user-data-dir=/Users/mac/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default`， but it also open new chrome, not the default one.